# Will Serverless support AWS DocumentDB?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, serverless

I work in a company that's using Serverless to build cloud-native applications and services. Today we use DynamoDB and SQL Databases with AWS Aurora.

We want to go with DocumentDB for our next application, but we could not find anything about Serverless and AWS DocumentDB. Does Serverless support AWS DocumentDB? If not, is there any plans to support it in the future?

Comment: I am curious - what are your requirements for a serverless offering for DocumentDB? I work on the DocumentDB product and would love to connect!

Answer (score 9):

Serverless supports any AWS resources that you can define using CloudFormation. As per the Serverless docs [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources/):

> Define your AWS resources in a property titled resources. What goes in
>   this property is raw CloudFormation template syntax, in YAML...

The YAML for creating a DocumentDB cluster is, going to look something like:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    DBCluster:
      Type: "AWS::DocDB::DBCluster"
      DeletionPolicy: Delete
      Properties:
        DBClusterIdentifier: "MyCluster"
        MasterUsername: "MasterUser"
        MasterUserPassword: "Password1234!"

    DBInstance:
      Type: "AWS::DocDB::DBInstance"
      Properties:
        DBClusterIdentifier: "MyCluster"
        DBInstanceIdentifier: "MyInstance"
        DBInstanceClass: "db.r4.large"
      DependsOn: DBCluster
```

You can find the other CloudFormation resources that you can define in the `resources` parameter of your Serverless.yaml [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_DocDB.html).

Answer (score 1):

DocumentDB is not a serverless service. You need to manage the backend server to use it.
Please refer to this blog: https://blogs.itemis.com/en/serverless-services-on-aws, you can see it is not in the list of "SERVERLESS SERVICES ON AWS".

Answer (score 1):

No, this won't support serverless, if you really want this you can go with DynamoDB. Also, can see differences if you want.

**DocumentDB**

- MongoDB is supported in this database, which provide ease to learn
- Stored procedures are needed in this, where data retrieval and data accumulation is done with help
- Document size is limited to 16MB and storage is maximized up to 64TB of data.
- Daily backups are managed by the database itself, and can be recovered whenever required
- This is costly as we require paying around $200/month even if the user uses only some instances of database or only used few hours.
- AWS is not involved in the user credentials stored area as that will be stored in DB directly
- Available in specific regions
- Can be easily migrated out of AWS into any MongoDB
- In case of primary node failure, service promotes read-replica to primary. Multi A-Z has to be configured by users. Backup can be copied across regions

**DynamoDB**

- MongoDB is not directly supported i this and even not easy to migrate from MongoDB to DynamoDB
- Stored procedures are not needed in this, which makes the process easier for users
- There is no limit in the document size as it can be scaled up to the size of user requirements
- Daily backups are not available which makes the user too backup the data which triggered explicitly by users, and can be recovered whenever needed
- There is initial cost associated with this, but overall cost is less. Also, on-demand pricing is available where user manage with the lesser amount of $1/month. 25GB data is provided for free in first stage.
- AWS controls the user access to the database through identity and access management where authentication and authorization is needed for low level as well
- Available in all regions
- Can not be easily migrated out of AWS into any MongoDB, you need to write a code to transform
- Support global tables, which protect users against regional failure. Data is automatically replicated across multiple AZs in a single region.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Document Db is not serverless database. You can check here https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34242126)